# Rails: display @cars as a comma-separated list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Based on this query:

```
@cars = Car.where("manufacturer_id IN ?", @mfts.select("id")).limit(30).select("id")
```

How can I display the cars' IDs in the view like this (or do I need to rewrite my query)?

`3,2,5,12,15,24,34,63,64,65,66,85`

Thanks a lot - I've looked for this but couldn't find the right question/answer.

---

One solution is to do:

```
#view
<% @cars.each do |c| %><%= c.id %>,<% end %>
```

I don't know if there's a better way to go about it - this obviously leaves a stray comma at the end of the list (which isn't a dealbreaker). Any more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One line:

```
<%= @cars.map(&:id).join(",") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that wonderful answer! How can I accomplish the same thing with an array? I have [3,2,5,12,15...] in an array and I just need to strip out the square brackets.

Comment: Simply `[3,2,5,12,15].join(",")`. The `@cars.map(&:id)` actually returns a array containing the ids.

Answer (score 8):

If writing `&:id` seems confusing, there's another way that's a little more readable.. If y'all want to access a method or attribute, it might look better to inline a block.

```
<%= @cars.map { |car| car.id }.join(", ") %>
```

P.S... another name for `map` is `collect`.. that's what it's called in Smalltalk.

Lookin' good!

Answer (score 6):

With Rails 3.0+ you can now write:

```
<%= @cars.map { |car| car.id }.to_sentence %>
```

Rails will appropriately add the comments and the word 'and' between the last two elements.